# Git: Check if file is part of a certain commit

Tags: git

I want to check if a certain file was part of a specified commit; if the source code at that time includes the above file. How may I achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

`git checkout <sha1 of commit>` then check if file is there`

if you want to check how the file was changed in the commit then:

`git diff <sha1 of commit before your commit> <sha1 of commit>`

To get a full log of commits `git log` (you can add `--oneline` for brevity)